# how to build a matrix UI?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build the following simple UI, but I am having a rough time coding it in the right way to achieve those multiples rectangles as table layout. I could code a really bad matrix, but how can I achieve the following design using HTML, and CSS , I know it;s really simple , but I am not sure how to correctly  [image: matrix]

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 600px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
}

.ex-col {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #555;
}

.ex-col h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid slategray;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ex-col h2>small {
  display: block;
  font-size: .9rem;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.ex-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


/* The list item element. Must be FLEX */

.ex-list>li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 70px;
}


/* The list heading element */

.ex-list h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border: 1px solid slategray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*  Set flex size to 50% of the parent element width. 
              This is a good way to make sure it is always 50% */
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.ex-list h3>small {
  font-size: .6em;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: lightgray;
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
}


/* The sub-menu element. Initial state is display:none */

.ex-list-sub {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: none;
}

.ex-list-sub:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.ex-list-sub>li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

.ex-list-sub>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.ex-list-sub>li>a:hover {
  background: #efefef;
}


/* THE HOVER ACTION */


/*  Set the hover on the parent element. 
            Has to be the parent because otherwise the pop-up would disappear when you hover over it */

.ex-list>li:hover .ex-list-sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="ex-col">
      <h2>
        Reconnaissance
        <small>10 Techniques</small>
      </h2>
      <ul class="ex-list">
        <li>
          <h3>
            Active Scanning
            <small>(0/2)</small>
          </h3>
          <ul class="ex-list-sub">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                          Scanning IP Blocks
                        </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                          Vulnerability Scanning
                        </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ex-col">
      <h2>
        Reconnaissance
        <small>10 Techniques</small>
      </h2>
      <ul class="ex-list">
        <li>
          <h3>
            Active Scanning
            <small>(0/2)</small>
          </h3>
          <ul class="ex-list-sub">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                          Scanning IP Blocks
                        </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                          Vulnerability Scanning
                        </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use table?

Comment: that's my last resource, but I want to do it the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe? I replicated it from your screenshot, is it missing anything?

```css
.column{
  float:left;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  width:120px;
}

.column .option{
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
  padding:10px;
  background:grey;
}

.column .option:first-child{
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
  <div class="option">Some text here</div>
</div>
```